# updating octave: linking the installation

Tags: terminal, installation, octave, homebrew

I have `OSX 10.10.5` with Octave `3.4.0` running (installed, who knows how, I did it a million different ways through port, file extraction, ftp, homebrew…). I tried to update my Programme (`brew install octave` or `sudo port install octave`) and Terminal spits out:

`Warning: octave-3.8.2 already installed, it's just not linked`

Okay, great. So I have a better programme somewhere installed. What now? How on earth am I supposed to “just **link**” the newer installation?

Answer (score 0):

If you install `octave` with Homebrew and it doesn't link it it should tell you why. You can force Homebrew to link `octave` with

```
$ brew link --overwrite octave
```

You can also add the `--dry-run` option to check and see what Homebrew will do to link `octave`

```
$ brew link --overwrite --dry-run octave
```

A possible reason for Homebrew not linking `octave` is that you've installed it by another method, MacPorts for instance. It is not recommended that you use both Homebrew and MacPorts on the same system.